# Creating folders issue with SkyDrive

Tags: c#, onedrive, liveconnect

I have read about creating folder in SkyDrive with Live SDK [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/hh561740.aspx#creating_folders) (the don't mention about 'boundary' parameter there), here is my code:

```
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.77e1a950546be643.77E1A950546BE643!202/files/");
    request.Method = "POST";
    string postData = "{name: \"My example folder\"}";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
```

And not sure whay I get a 400 returned:

> { "error": { "code": "request_header_invalid", "message": "The
>   provided header 'Content-Type' is missing a required parameter
>   'boundary'." } }

What I am doing wrong? Do i missing anything?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hi all, how stupid I am! My path is worng, it should be "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/folder.77e1a950546be643.77E1A950546BE643!202" (without the "/files/")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the WindowsLiveClient rather than making your own webrequest from scratch. I tried the example code on the documentation and it's worked fine with me. This assumes that people are already signed in to Windows Live, with the session stored in "session".

```
if (session == null)
{
    infoTextBlock.Text = "You must sign in first.";
}
else
{
    Dictionary<string, object> folderData = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    folderData.Add("name", "A brand new folder");
    LiveConnectClient client = new LiveConnectClient(session);
    client.PostCompleted += 
        new EventHandler<LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs>(CreateFolder_Completed);
    client.PostAsync("me/skydrive", folderData);
}
```

And then there's a function to be triggered when the operation completes, for catching errors.

```
void CreateFolder_Completed(object sender, LiveOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        infoTextBlock.Text = "Folder created.";
    }
    else
    {
        infoTextBlock.Text = "Error calling API: " + e.Error.ToString();
    }
}
```

According to w3, the error you got occurs when you're making an [HTTP206 request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html), a multipart request. Windows Live's [REST API documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) also talks about this, but not in the context of making folders, which suggests that the split request is done somewhere in the built-in LiveConnectClient.